# How do I locate the tag containing this text?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

I am using Open::URI and Nokogiri to scrape a Google search page:

```
 require 'open-uri'
 require 'nokogiri'
 url = http://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=toys&start=0&num=&complete=0
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
 mas = doc.css('li.g')[7]
 mas.at_css('.mas-row')
```

From this result I am interested in just one result:

```
"Amazon.co.uk: Toys - Harry Potter: Toys & Games"
```

and I would like to get the data from `"div class mas-row"`.

I can not find it. I looked in the "doc" variable and it can not be found.
After that I looked for the text that is in that "div" and for the first div a part of the text was found but nothing from the next div.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `div` with `mas-row` is included in the HTML. It's rendered by JavaScript.

Use a library that can handle JavaScript, such as selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's **not** rendered by JavaScript. Secondly, it may return nothing because Google blocks requests without browser-like `user-agent`. [What is my `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent)? Thirdly, If you want to retrieve only one (*first*) result, you can use `css`/`xpath` and `nokogiri` [`at_css`/`at_css` shortcuts](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#single-results), e.g:

```rb
doc.css(".yuRUbf a h3/text()")  #=> Harry Potter: Toys &amp; Games - Amazon.co.uk ...
```

Code:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'
require 'httparty'

headers = {
  "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  q: "Amazon.co.uk: Toys - Harry Potter: Toys & Games",
  hl: "en"
}

response = HTTParty.get('https://www.google.com/search',
                        query: params,
                        headers: headers)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)

# extract all organic resutlts
puts doc.css(".yuRUbf a h3/text()"),
     doc.css(".yuRUbf a/@href")

---
=begin
harry potter: Toys Store - Amazon.co.uk
harry potter toys - Amazon.com
harry potter: Toys &amp; Games - Amazon.com
harry potter toys: Toys &amp; Games - Amazon.com
Toys &amp; Games - Amazon.com
Harry Potter: Toys &amp; Games - Amazon.com
1-48 of 405 results for "harry potter lego" - Amazon
harry potter lego sets - Amazon.com
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Toys-Games-Harry-Potter/s?rh=n%3A468292%2Cp_89%3AHarry+Potter
https://www.amazon.co.uk/harry-potter-toys/s?k=harry+potter+toys
https://www.amazon.co.uk/harry-potter-Toys-Store/s?k=harry+potter&rh=n%3A468292
https://www.amazon.com/harry-potter-toys/s?k=harry+potter+toys
https://www.amazon.com/harry-potter-Toys-Games/s?k=harry+potter&rh=n%3A165793011
https://www.amazon.com/harry-potter-toys-Games/s?k=harry+potter+toys&rh=n%3A165793011
https://www.amazon.com/toys/b?ie=UTF8&node=165793011
https://www.amazon.com/Toys-Games-Harry-Potter/s?rh=n%3A165793011%2Cp_lbr_characters_browse-bin%3AHarry+Potter
https://www.amazon.com/harry-potter-lego/s?k=harry+potter+lego
https://www.amazon.com/harry-potter-lego-sets/s?k=harry+potter+lego+sets
=end
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve this by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan. One of the main differences is that you only need to iterate over a structured `json`.

Code to integrate:

```rb
require 'google_search_results' 

params = {
  api_key: ENV["API_KEY"],
  engine: "google",
  q: "Amazon.co.uk: Toys - Harry Potter: Toys & Games",
  hl: "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch.new(params)
hash_results = search.get_hash

# [0] first element from organic results
puts hash_results[:organic_results][0][:title], 
     hash_results[:organic_results][0][:link]

#=> Harry Potter: Toys & Games - Amazon.co.uk
#=> https://www.amazon.co.uk/Toys-Games-Harry-Potter/s?rh=n%3A468292%2Cp_89%3AHarry+Potter
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.